# How do I link an Excel OptionButton to a cell in a worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-automation, radio-button

**Context:**

- Document-level VSTO
- Visual Studio 2017 / C#
- Excel Designer

**Scenario:**

Two buttons; Yes & No.

**Expectation:**

When I click Yes, cell B9 value becomes 1.

When I click  No, cell B9 value becomes 2.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click the **Yes** option button
2. Click **Format Control**
3. Under **Control** tab > **Value** options, select **Checked**
4. **Cell link**: $B$9
5. Click OK

Now..

Clicking Yes, B9 will have a 1.

Clicking  No, B9 will have a 2.